# Mapstruct compile only changed files with maven

Tags: java, maven, build, mapstruct

is there a way to clean and compile only changed classes when working with mapstruct and maven?
For example, in my project I have lots of mapstruct interfaces which, once compiled, generates implementations in the target folder. but I need to avoid re-compiling those classes that i didn't change to ensure a fastest build.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I provided an answer please consider to accept it as answer if it satisfied the requirement to improve community otherwise feel free to add comment.

Answer (score 1):

The recompile of the project didn't run the annotation processor. MapStruct is invoked by the Java compiler and the maven-compiler-plugin is responsible for cleaning up the folder with the generated classes, thus it will go through all mapper interfaces.

Comment: For more info about annotation processing please see the page 5 on https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/pdf/mapstruct-reference-guide.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Set "Build Automatically" on in your IDE. If you're using Eclipse it's located at the top in "Project".

Comment: Welcome to SO, the question is not about building automatically the project, its about avoiding recompilation of pre-compiled interfaces .